# How to start with left menu collapsed

Tags: react-admin

Is there an easy was to start with the left menu collapsed or do I need to update the layout ?
I'd like to have the menu collapsed by default with only the icons visible.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean Sidebar when saying "left menu", you can hide it by turning on the user saga (the toggle action will continue to work):

```
// closeSidebarSaga.js

import {
  put,
  takeEvery,
} from 'redux-saga/effects'

import {
  REGISTER_RESOURCE, // React-admin 3.5.0 
  setSidebarVisibility,
} from 'react-admin'

function* closeSidebar(action) {
  try {
    if (action.payload) {
      yield put(setSidebarVisibility(false))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('closeSidebar:', error)
  }
}

function* closeSidebarSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(REGISTER_RESOURCE, closeSidebar) 
}

export default closeSidebarSaga

// App.js:

import closeSidebarSaga from './closeSidebarSaga'

<Admin customSagas={[ closeSidebarSaga ]} ... }>
...
</Admin>
```

In the react-admin library itself, apparently a bug, at some point in time after the login, action SET_SIDEBAR_VISIBILITY = true is called!

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxAlex How do you activate it? I'm not familiar with sagas. I tried calling it when App.js mounts, but I can't see any change.

Comment: The react-admin has a special opportunity to connect:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas

Comment: It does not work for me anymore. It used to work, but I realized just now that it does not work anymore. I am not sure exactly when it stopped working as i just upgraded to react-admin 3.5.0 and I also implemented MSAL authentication which may be affecting it.
Any idea?

Comment: Hello, in version react-admin 3.5.0 removed "dispactch action setSidebarVisibility(true)" and now this solution will not work:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/4677/files/7df979c1beb165c8a56e246642659abd77d31070

Comment: Alternatively you can bind to any other event when the application starts:
"yield takeEvery(REGISTER_RESOURCE, closeSidebar)"

Answer (score 5):

You can set the initial state when loading Admin, then there will be no moment when the Sidebar is visible at the beginning, and then it is hidden:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#initialstate

```
const initialState = {
  admin: { ui: { sidebarOpen: false, viewVersion: 0 } }
}    

<Admin
  initialState={initialState}
  ...
</Admin>
```

Comment: hey MaxAlex, this is neat - but are these (and others) state values defined anywhere?  The official documentation merely acknowledges the existence of the initialState prop.  I'm looking to fix the sideBar in position, so it never scrolls off the screen, and poking around looking for a solution.  thanks

Comment: Hi, Andy, I didn't see this in the official documentation, the contents of Redux-state can be viewed through dev-tools in the browser. Perhaps to do this, you need to redefine the CSS for the Sidebar component.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the left sideBar divider we need to dispatch **setSidebarVisibility** action .

This is an example to hide the sideBar by using **useDispatch** react-redux hook & 
 **setSidebarVisibility** action inside the layout file (layout.tsx):

```
import React from 'react';

/**
* Step 1/2 :Import required hooks (useEffect & useDispatch)
*/ 
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { Layout, Sidebar ,setSidebarVisibility} from 'react-admin';
import AppBar from './AppBar';
import Menu from './Menu';
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from './themes';
import { AppState } from '../types';

const CustomSidebar = (props: any) => <Sidebar {...props} size={200} />;

export default (props: any) => {
    const theme = useSelector((state: AppState) =>
        state.theme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme
    );

    /**
    * Step 2/2 : dispatch setSidebarVisibility action
    */
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setSidebarVisibility(false));
    });

    return (
        <Layout
            {...props}
            appBar={AppBar}
            sidebar={CustomSidebar}
            menu={Menu}
            theme={theme}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **Redux** is not used anymore by ReactAdmin, you need to adapt the **local storage** instead to hide the sidebar. Call this in your `App.tsx` class:

```
const store = localStorageStore();
store.setItem("sidebar.open", false);
```